# why can't I pass an array as props from one js to another?

Tags: reactjs

I have three js file `App.js`, `PeopleData.js`, `PeopleDetail.js`

`App.js` is the main application containing all other components including `PeopleDetail.js`
`PeopleData.js` contains JSON array data that is imported to `App.js`
`PeopleDetail.js` is the components displaying the data from `PeopleData.js`

But I was trying to pass the JSON from `App.js` to `PeopleDetail.js` as props, it would change it to an object instead of an array.

This is `App.js`

```
import React from "react";
import PeopleData from "./PeopleData";
import PeopleDetail from "./PeopleDetail";

function App() {
console.log(PeopleData)
  return (
    <div>
          <PeopleDetail props={PeopleData} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Even I was using the console.log to make sure the JSON I am passing is an array, it would still end up being an object in the `PeopleDetail.js` and I can't use the map function on it.

This is `PeopleDetail.js`

```
import React from "react";

function PeopleDetail(props) {
  console.log(props);
  const list = props.map((people) => (
    <div key={people.id}>
      <li>
        <h1>{people.name}</h1>
      </li>
    </div>
  ));

  return <div>{list}</div>;
}

export default PeopleDetail;
```

This is `PeopleDetail.js`

```
const peopleData = [
  {
    name: "Peter",
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    name: "Tom",
    id: 2,
  },
];
export default peopleData;
```

Any help would be appreciated!!! Thank you so much!

Comment: Should be function PeopleDetail({props})

Answer (score 1):

You need to pull `peopleData` out of your props object. You can use a destructuring approach like below or just change your map to `props.people.map(...)`. I recommend naming your attribute something other than props, so you don't get confused with the normal props object. Right now you have an props object with a props array.

```
import React from "react";
import PeopleData from "./PeopleData";
import PeopleDetail from "./PeopleDetail";

function App() {
console.log(PeopleData)
  return (
    <div>
          <PeopleDetail people={PeopleData} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React from "react";

function PeopleDetail({ people }) {
  console.log(people);
  const list = people.map((person) => (
    <div key={person.id}>
      <li>
        <h1>{person.name}</h1>
      </li>
    </div>
  ));

  return <div>{list}</div>;
}

export default PeopleDetail;
```

Comment: It works instantly! thanks for the help.  So everything I pass as props would end up being an object?

Comment: All the attributes passed on your component is joined into a single object passed to that component function. Since you only have one attribute it's basically wrapped in an object. If you had a people and name attribute on your component, you'd have an object with a people and name property passed to the component.